# how to pass id from url to post_save_redirect in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have several objects in the database. Url to edit an object using the generic view looks like `site.com/cases/edit/123/` where `123` is an id of the particular object. Consider the `cases/url.py` contents:

```
url(r'edit/(?P<object_id>\d{1,5})/$', update_object, { ... 'post_save_redirect': ???}, name = 'cases_edit'),
```

where `update_object` is a generic view. How to construct the `post_save_redirect` to point to `site.com/cases/edit/123/`. My problem is, that I don't know how to pass the `id` of the object to redirect function. I tried something like:

```
'post_save_redirect': 'edit/(?P<object_id>\d{1,5})/'
'post_save_redirect': 'edit/' + str(object_id) + '/'
```

but obviously none of these work. `reverse` function was suggested, but how to pass the particular `id`?

```
'post_save_redirect': reverse('cases_edit', kwargs = {'object_id': ???})
```

`{% url %}` in the temple also requires passing the `id` of the particular object. The `id` can be passed via `extra_context`:

```
extra_context = {'object_id': ???}
```

In all the cases the problem is to get `object_id` from the url.

regards
chriss

Comment: You really don't provide enough information. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short what you need to do is wrap the update_object function.

```
def update_object_wrapper(request, object_id, *args, **kwargs):
    redirect_to = reverse('your object edit url name', object_id)
    return update_object(request, object_id, post_save_redirect=redirect_to, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read up on the [reverse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/?from=olddocs#reverse) function.

Second, read up on the `{%` [url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) `%}` tag.

You use the `reverse` function in a view to generate the expected redirect location.

Also, you should be using the `{% url %}` tag in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-create-object

post_save_redirect may contain dictionary string formatting, which will be interpolated against the object's field attributes. For example, you could use post_save_redirect="/polls/%(slug)s/".